# Send email to report an error with user information in Handler.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I send an email with bug information when laravel has an exception. But I would like to include the user information logged in at the time of the error.

In the Handler.php

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    parent::report($exception);

    Mail::send('emails.errorreport', ['e' => $exception], function($message)
    {
        $message->to('email@email.com')->subject('Report error');
    });
}
```

In the emails/errorreport.blade.php

```
<h3>Error Information</h3>
<p><strong>Date:</strong> {{ date('M d, Y H:iA') }}</p>
<p><strong>Message:</strong> {{ $e->getMessage() }}</p>
<p><strong>Code:</strong> {{ $e->getCode() }}</p>
<p><strong>File:</strong> {{ $e->getFile() }}</p>
<p><strong>Line:</strong> {{ $e->getLine() }}</p>
<h3>Stack trace:</h3>
<pre>{{ $e->getTraceAsString() }}</pre>

@if(Auth::user())
      <p><strong>   User: </strong> ID: {{Auth::user()->id}} / Name: {{Auth::user()->name}} / Email: {{Auth::user()->email}}</p>
@endif
```

It does not work.

The error information is sent correctly, but not from the user. Even when I have a user logged the "***if (Auth :: user ()***)" returns false.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception or error, post the line it occurred on and the details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: The error information is sent correctly, but not from the user. Even when I have a user logged the "if (Auth :: user ())" returns false.

Comment: I don't use laravel, but have you tried passing ```['e' => $exception, 'user'=>Auth::user()]``` or building the array before calling ```Mail::send``` and passing user to the mail?

Comment: Yes, this was also an alternative that did not work.

Comment: Again, just taking a stab, but you verified (log or debug) that Auth::user() is correctly working inside the scope of your report() function? If so, it might have to do with your @if/@endif processing instead.

Comment: how about `@if(auth()->check())`

Answer (score 0):

Use check(), returns true if the user logged in... Auth::user() returns the user object...  the opposite is Auth::guest() that will return true if the user is a guest...

```
@if (Auth::check())
      <p><strong>   User: </strong> ID: {{Auth::user()->id}} / Name: {{Auth::user()->name}} / Email: {{Auth::user()->email}}</p>
@endif
```